# Find where a program is installed in Linux

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-10.04, package-management

After installing a program using a package manager where is the information about where the program was installed and in which menu category it can be found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For where the program was installed (including all of the supporting files, so it can be a long list that you would need to search through)

```
dpkg-query -L firefox
```

For the menu item containing the package, look for a file in /usr/share/menu in the output of dpkg-query:

```
dpkg-query -L firefox | grep /usr/share/menu
```

In that file you should find "section=".  The string after that text should indicate where in the menu system you would find the link to the application.

For information about what categories Ubuntu put the package into, you might try:

```
aptitude show firefox
```

Answer (score 19):

Running `which [application name]` should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If by "program" you meant the binary, it usually goes to /usr/bin

Resources go to /usr/share/

User specific configs usually are created in . in the user's home directory

Comment: The binary and where it's shortcut can be found in the menu.